# Fetch to render a page from the server?

Tags: javascript, express

Is there any point in using fetch to get a page from the server? I was looking at some page navigation I had in my project when I came across this block of code one of my group members wrote.

```
fetch("/user/home")
    .then((response) => {
        if(!response.ok)
            throw new Error("Can't go to home.");

        location.href = response.url;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error("Error:", error));
```

The `GET` in question basically does this:

```
router.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  res.render("userhome");
});
```

This basically does the same thing as if I typed this out to replace it:

```
location.href = "/user/home";
```

What is the point of navigating between pages with 6 lines when you can do it in 1? Am I not understanding something important?

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who wrote the code, rather than randos on the internet? We can guess; they can tell you exactly what they were thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yeah, `location.href = "/user/home";`
is simpler and more direct for pure navigation purposes than the first one involving a fetch request. If all you need to do is navigate to a new page, it's perfectly acceptable (and preferable) to use the single line of code.

However, using fetch to make a request to the server can provide more granular control and has several benefits depending on the requirements:

Fetch allows for better error handling. If there's a server error when trying to access `/user/home`, fetch allows you to catch that error and handle it gracefully in your application. Directly setting location.href wouldn't give you any information about server errors, the browser would just attempt to load the new URL and possibly display a default error page.

Fetch allows you to check for conditions before actually navigating to the new page. For instance, you could check if the response status is 200 (OK) before redirecting. If the status is anything other than 200, you could prevent the redirect and possibly display a message to the user.

But keep in mind that code is often about more than just achieving a function— it is also about building in flexibility, robustness, and future-proofing. The fetch method could provide a framework for more complex behaviours in the future, avoid over-engineering it in advance, but do have a think about what you might need to do in the future.

In your example it seems like the fetch request isn't doing much more than the single line `location.href` would do - so in this case the fetch request might be overkill.